# SQL query "translated" to one that Django will accept, anyone? Please (python)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, chain

Can anyone "translate" this MySQL query to  Django chain or Q(). This is just an example (but valid) query, but I want to see it with my own eyes, because Django documentation doesn't look very noob friendly in this aspect and I couldn't get those chains and stuff to work.

```
mysql -> SELECT position, COUNT(position) FROM    
      -> (SELECT * FROM log WHERE (aspect LIKE 'es%' OR brand LIKE '%pj%')
      -> AND tag IN ('in','out')) AS list
      -> GROUP BY position ORDER BY COUNT(position) DESC;
```

While I think chaining filters would be more convenient for me in the future, this  below just seems way more straightforward at the moment.

```
query = "the query from above"

cursor.execute(query)

[new_list.append([item for item in row ]) for row in cursor]
```

...or should I just quit()

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Count,Q
myfilter = [Q(aspect__startswith="es")|Q(brand__contains="pj"),tag__in=['in','out']]
            #   condition 1           OR     condition2      AND     condition3
qry = Log.objects.filter(*myfilter).values('position').annotate({"count":Count('position')})
print(qry.values())
```

I think maybe gets you the same answer using django ... close anyway I think

whether it is better or not i suppose is in the eye of the beholder

Answer (score 0):

```
myfilter = Q(aspect__startswith="es") | Q(brand__contains="pj"), Q(tag__in=['in', 'out'])
qry = Log.objects.filter(*myfilter).values('position').annotate(Count('position')).order_by('-position__count')
```

had to add **Q** before **tag__in**
brackets on **myfilter** did not make a difference
**annotate({"count":Count('position')})** gave an error *QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s)*
and to sort in descending order had to add
**.order_by('-position__count')**

output is a dictionary, but that's perfect for displaying on the website

So You were close. Now the data is matching mysql output and I understand it better how to do the QuerySets and filters. Thanks